# Debugging nfs volume "Unable to attach or mount volumes for pod"

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, mount, nfs, persistent-volumes

I've set up an nfs server that serves a RMW pv according to the example at https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs

This setup works fine for me in lots of production environments, but in some specific GKE cluster instance, mount stopped working after pods restarted.

From kubelet logs I see the following repeating many times

> Unable to attach or mount volumes for pod "api-bf5869665-zpj4c_default(521b43c8-319f-425f-aaa7-e05c08282e8e)": unmounted volumes=[shared-mount], unattached volumes=[geekadm-net deployment-role-token-6tg9p shared-mount]: timed out waiting for the condition; skipping pod

> Error syncing pod 521b43c8-319f-425f-aaa7-e05c08282e8e ("api-bf5869665-zpj4c_default(521b43c8-319f-425f-aaa7-e05c08282e8e)"), skipping: unmounted volumes=[shared-mount], unattached volumes=[geekadm-net deployment-role-token-6tg9p shared-mount]: timed out waiting for the condition

Manually mounting the nfs on any of the nodes work just fine: `mount -t nfs <service ip>:/ /tmp/mnt`

How can I further debug the issue? Are there any other logs I could look at besides kubelet?

Comment: Deleting the nfs-server service and pvc and re-creating them fixed the issue. Still no idea how to debug it next time.

Comment: Report the issue to google. Refer to the [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) to raise an issue. In that link, Click on **Create new Google Kubernetes Engine issue** and raise the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In case the pod gets kicked out of the node because the mount is too slow, you may see messages like that in logs.

Kubelets even inform about this issue in logs.
**Sample log from Kubelets:**
Setting volume ownership for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/c9987636-acbe-4653-8b8d-
aa80fe423597/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pvc-fbae0402-b8c7-4bc8-b375-
1060487d730d and fsGroup set. If the volume has a lot of files then setting
volume ownership could be slow, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69699

**Cause:**
The pod.spec.securityContext.fsGroup setting causes kubelet to run chown and chmod on all the files in the volumes mounted for given pod. This can be a very time consuming thing to do in case of big volumes with many files.

By default, Kubernetes recursively changes ownership and permissions for the contents of each volume to match the fsGroup specified in a Pod's securityContext when that volume is mounted. From the [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods).

**Solution:**
You can deal with it in the following ways.

1. Reduce the number of files in the volume.
2. Stop using the fsGroup setting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify an nfs version when mounting command-line? I had the same issue on AKS, but inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/71789693/1382108 I checked the nfs versions. Noticed my PV had a vers=3. When I tried mounting command-line using `mount -t nfs -o vers=3` command just hung, with `vers=4.1` it worked immediately. Changed the version in my PV and next Pod worked just fine.